# Is there any way to change the appearance of MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, mapkit, apple-maps

Is there a way to manipulate the look of MKMapView (colors etc) like with Core Image and photos? I thought about making the map black and white or something like that. Someone I know did this in order to display a tiny map on the display of a Metawatch by basically taking snapshots of an MKMapView, turning them into binary images and sending them to the watch.

I need to do a similiar thing in real time (and on the iPhone's display). Hope you guys understand what I'm trying to ask here :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Check here](http://www.shawngrimes.me/2010/12/mapkit-overlays-session-1-overlay-map/)

Comment: I am actually trying to manipulate the map *itself*, but thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Not MapKit directly, but the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mobile) can do that and more, plus is meant to behave like MapKit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following question (and mainly the answer) as great solution
[Hiding mapview when mapoverlay is visible ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613833/hiding-mapview-when-mapoverlay-is-visible-ios7)

using MKTileOverlay and http://maps.stamen.com site

by the way .... they have http://maps.stamen.com/#toner/12/37.7706/-122.3782 which is a black and white map