# iOS7 MKTileOverlay Cached (Save cached method?)

Tags: dictionary, ios7, mapkit, mktileoverlay

I working on map app and consider to using new function in iOS7 for MKTileOverlay and MKTileOverlayRenderer. But I googled around with no luck.

I found this thread, tell me to do subclassing MKTileOverlay

[Hiding mapview when mapoverlay is visible ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613833/hiding-mapview-when-mapoverlay-is-visible-ios7/19641811#19641811)

Code from thread:

```
-(void)loadTileAtPath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path result:(void (^)(NSData *, NSError *))result
{
    NSData *tile = [self someHowGetTileImageIntoNSDataBaseOnPath:path];
    if (tile) {
        result(tile, nil);
    } else {
        result(nil, [NSError errorWithDomain: CUSTOM_ERROR_DOMAIN code: 1 userInfo:nil]);
    }
}
```

Question is: 
`[self someHowGetTileImageIntoNSDataBaseOnPath:path]` is load tileData 
But How can I save tileData to DB?

And if I can get tileData from Database `result(tile, nil);` is enough for make overlay show up?
Or I need to do something else after overwrite `loadTileAtPath:result:`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorry for asking stupid question, Now I think I understand more about this MKTileOverlay.

```
-(void)loadTileAtPath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path result:(void (^)(NSData *, NSError *))result
{
    NSData *tile = [self someHowGetTileImageIntoNSDataBaseOnPath:path];
    if (tile) {
        result(tile, nil);
    } else {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[self URLForTilePath:path]];
        //Or you can using asynchronous request.
        NSData *tileData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
        [self saveCachedWithData:tileData];
        result(tileData, nil);
    }
}
```

May be looking around for a day make me stun and cannot understand it's library,
Sorry again and hope this may help someone who face same problem.